# How to set JSBin themes?

Tags: jsbin

I read that you can set different themes for JSBin. I saw it here: http://elijahmanor.com/custom-jsbin-code-editor-settings/

It doesn't appear to work for me, though. I went to my browser's console and entered: `jsbin.settings.editor.theme = "monokai";` and then refreshed the JSBin page, but the theme did not change. I also tried setting it in JSBin's console. I didn't expect that to work, and in fact, it did not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the editor theme on the [editor settings](http://jsbin.com/account/editor) page.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the console of element inspector (so yes, browser console not jsbin's) at top of log, youll see this line indicating settings is locked by default:

```
To edit settings, type this string ..
```

You might have to refresh to reget a string if you've cleared console manually. Tripped me too at first. Enjoy!